# about the compactness of minimal surfaces

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

If a Caccioppoli set $A$ is of minimal perimeter in every compact set $K$ contained in some open set, can we say that $A$ is of minimal perimeter in the open set? If not, please construct a counterexample. This problems arises when I read lemma 9.1 in the book of Guisti, **Minimal Surfaces and Functions of Bounded Variation**. The author explains Caccioppoli sets of least area in this way, and sometimes he uses the term *Caccioppoli sets of least perimeter*.